# ¿Afecta al uso de recursos importar con * un paquete de Java?

Tags: java, importación

Ya sé que siempre es mejor importar las clases que necesites de una en una. A no ser que necesites una gran cantidad de un mismo paquete.
También sé que por temas de nombres, puede ocasionar problemas y una peor legibilidad del código.

Pero mi pregunta es, ¿afecta en algo el que importe todo un paquete así?

```
import nombrePaquete.*;
```

He leído que los import se van haciendo dinámicamente a medida que se utilizan clases en concreto, pero no sé si afecta al tamaño final en disco de las aplicaciones, o carga en RAM, uso de CPU, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No afectan en el uso de recursos en tiempo de ejecución.

> A no ser que necesites una gran cantidad de un mismo paquete

De hecho aunque encesites muchas del mismo paquete va a ser mejor usar importaciones de clases singulares

¿Por qué?

Algunos motivos importantes pueden ser:

- colisión de nombres de las clases

  ```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.util.*;
  // ...
  List decisiones = new List(); // error de compilación!
  ```
- clases que desaparecen en versiones posteriores de las librerías

  ```
  Cannot resolve symbol: Bootstrapper //import asterisco
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper //import singular
  ```

Recuerda que los imports son una ayuda al compilador, si no deseas usar imports la opción es usar nombres totalmente calificados, pero casi nadie lo usa debido a que el tamaño del código aumenta considerablemente

Comment: Vale, en tiempo de ejecución, no afectan, ¿pero en compilación? ¿Aumentan el tamaño de los programas?

Comment: no, el tamaño del bytecode es exactamente el mismo, lo único que cambia es el tiempo que tarda en compilar pero es practicamente imperceptible, aunque dicho sea de paso eso no era parte de tu pregunta si tienes más preguntas no las hagas en las respuestas, crea una nueva publicación para las preguntas adicionales

Answer (score 0):

La única función de la palabra clave [`import`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) en Java es evitar tener que escribir el nombre completo de las clases y demás símbolos a los que quieres acceder.

Considera este código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

Si no usaras el import, podrías seguir usando la clase `Scanner`. La diferencia es que para poder hacerlo tendrás que escribir su nombre completo. Así:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

---

El único inconveniente de usar `import` es que si importas dos clases con el mismo nombre de diferentes paquetes el compilador no va a saber a cuál haces referencia.

Si conoces C# o C++, el `import` cumple la misma función que `using` en ellos.

Comment: Por lo tanto, me imagino en base a tu respuesta, que es lo mismo a nivel de recursos hacer el import que no hacerlo.

Comment: @a_dev Exacto. El que puede que sufra un poco más es el IDE teniendo en cuenta todos los imports para el auto completado pero no tengo pruebas sobre eso.